# Why can't we do bitwise operations on Bools?

Tags: solidity, bytes

So I'm running an if/then comparator function with bools.  It's essentially and xor function but when I tried `a ^ b` i get **operator not compatible with types bool and bool.**

Given that bools (in general) are logic primitives, I'm wondering why we cannot bitwise them in solidity?

Can this be done in inline assembly instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a general difference between logical and bitwise operators, logical operators can only be applied to booleans and bitwise operators can only be applied to "bitfields" like `bytes32`.

Of course the concept of "logical exclusive disjunction" exists, but there is no actual operator by that name.

Having said that, `a != b` should do the trick.

Comment: for an example, a = 1001 and b = 0001.
So if you are looking for b in a, a ^ b should return true. but a != b will return false since they are not the same, and it is not a binary comparison. The nearest I can get to this is simple:
(b == (a & b)) which would return True. Thoughts?