# Possible to do bitwise operator on byte array (bytes)?

Tags: solidity, bytes

Or do only bitfields like bytes32 support the xor function (a ^ b)?

Related, [Why can't we do bitwise operations on Bools?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6829/why-cant-we-do-bitwise-operations-on-bools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#value-types for which operators are defined for which types, but no, bitwise operators aren't defined on dynamically-sized arrays.